# Get rid of Unread Mail folder, restore emails to Inbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I didn't know the Unread folder existed until I got in trouble for not responding to an email I never saw that came when I was out of the office. I'm using Outlook 2003 on Windows 7.

Can you please tell me how to move all the unread messages back into my inbox and delete this unread mail folder so it won't eat my emails any more?

Answer (score 1):

The Unread "folder" is not a real folder. It runs a search on your mailboxes and shows all messages that are not yet read, in any of your main mailbox folders.

Because it's not a real folder, you cannot move things out of the folder.

Also, because it's not a real folder, if you don't want it, you can just right-click on it and delete it. Because all the emails "in" the Unread "folder" actually exist elsewhere in your mailbox no messages will be lost by deleting the Unread folder.

But, it sounds as though you could benefit from knowing about this folder and using it. Because it shows all of your currently unread messages it can be helpful for seeing what you have not yet seen.